# FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to setup the core Facebook SDK into my project. My project is Swift based, yet the SDK is ObjectiveC.

I copied both `Bolts.framework` and `FBSDKCoreKit.Framework` into my project. I setup a bridging file which works perfectly. Then I added the following to my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

The project builds, although crashes on start when running on my device with the error `FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit: no matching architecture in universal wrapper`.

Comment: In terminal, `cd` to where your `FBSDCoreKit.framework` is and run `lipo -i FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit`.

Do any of the architectures printed out from `lipo` match the architecture of your device?

Comment: Did you try installing the SDK using cocoapods

Comment: @Fizzix, did you find the answer to this? I'm finding Facebook's SDKs (and programming practices in general) to be really awful.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the wrong frameworks are being included.

Delete all FBSDK and Bolts frameworks from your embedded binaries sections.
Now click the plus sign and add them again making sure to select the "iOS" versions of each.